# How to copy files to a Docker volume and use that volume with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

- There is a webservice running in a Docker container.
- This webservice relies on big json files to boot.

I create a Docker volume to store the json files with `docker volume create my-api-files`.

Here is the `docker-compose` file for the webservice:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  my-api:
    image: node:alpine
    expose:
      - ${NODE_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./:/api
      - my-api-files:/files
    working_dir: /api
    command: npm run start

volumes: 
  my-api-files: 
    external: true
```

**Now, how can I copy the json files to the `my-api-files` docker volume before to start the the webservice with `docker-compose up`?**

Comment: you dont need to copy. docker volume will mount files directory into my-api-files directory inside the container

Comment: I don't want to store the files inside the docker container. That's why I want to use a separate volume

Comment: There is [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176561/copying-files-to-a-container-with-docker-compose) from 2017 on StackOverflow and there is an open issue [docker-compose copy file or directory to container](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5523) for docker-compose. AFAIK this problem does not have a direct solution but one can work around it

Comment: You don't need to copy anything. You can just mount a directory on the host into a path on the container. The first part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181484/14357) shows you how.

Answer (score 4):

You could run a temporary container with that volume and a bind mount to your host files and run a copy from there:

```
docker run --rm -it -v my-api-files:/temporary -v $PWD/jsonFileLocation:/big-data alpine cp /big-data/*.json /temporary
docker run --rm -it -v my-api-files:/test alpine ls /test
```

You should see your JSON files in there.

**EDIT**: Of course, replace `$PWD/jsonFileLocation` with your JSON file location and your operating system's syntax.