# Why is my volume not copying over to its docker container?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run a webserver container with nginx and a php-fpm server running a Laravel application. The directory houses a frontend and backend directory so my paths are not off in the configuration files.

I setup a docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: webserver.docker
    volumes:
      - /home/colesam/Documents/code/todo/backend:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - backend
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.docker
    volumes:
      - ./home/colesam/Documents/code/todo/backend:/var/www
```

And php-fpm Dockerfile (backend.docker)

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
VOLUME ["/var/www"]
RUN ls -al /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN composer install
```

And the nginx webserver Dockerfile (webserver.docker)

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www
```

For some reason when I run `docker-compose up -d --build` I always fail at this step of the build process:

```
Step 13/13 : RUN composer install
 ---> Running in 65bb97f03004
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c composer install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

From the last line of the output it looks like it failed because /var/www/was empty and didn't have the files copied over like `composer.json`. I looked around a lot and this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176561/copying-files-to-a-container-with-docker-compose) seemed to be the most related to what was happening but I think I'm already following everything the accepted answer suggests.

Do I need to include a `COPY` or `ADD` command even though I'm mounting the folder through a volume?

Comment: Nothing in the Dockerfile ever sees volumes at all.

Comment: The host volume path of your webserver and backend is different.

Comment: maybe remove the "." in this statement: " volumes:
      - ./home/colesam/Documents/code/todo/backend:/var/www"

Answer (score 1):

The build phase does not see any mounted volumes. The only thing that is available to "build" are the things defined in the `backend.docker` and in the compose section of build:

```
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.docker
```

> Do I need to include a COPY or ADD command even though I'm mounting the folder through a volume?

Yes, modify your `backend.docker` similar to this

```
...
WORKDIR /var/www
ADD composer.json .
RUN composer install
```